# Shows ClassCastException while performing drag and drop in android

Tags: java, android, xml, classcastexception

I'm performing simple drag and drop in android. Log message shows ClassCastException and some error in line number 70 of the java code.
Line number 70 is inside onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragEvent) method and in case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP. That line is within ** **. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

THIS IS THE JAVA CODE

```
package com.example.anandzoom.draganddrop;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener,View.OnDragListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.text_drag).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.text_drop).setOnDragListener(this);

}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
{
    if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragEvent)
{
    int action = dragEvent.getAction();
    switch (action)
    {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        {
            Log.v("DragAndDrop", "ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
            break;
        }
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        {
            Log.v("DragAndDrop", "ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
            break;
        }
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        {
            Log.v("DragAndDrop", "ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
            break;
        }
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        {
            Log.v("DragAndDrop", "ACTION_DROP");

            TextView view = (TextView) dragEvent.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) layoutview.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
          **LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;**
            container.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        {
            Log.v("DragAndDrop", "ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

THIS IS THE XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.anandzoom.draganddrop.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_drag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drag me"
        android:textSize="19sp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_drop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drop here"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

THE LOG MESSAGE SHOWS THE ERROR: ClassCastException

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-13 14:58:35.635 1270-1270/com.example.anandzoom.draganddrop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.anandzoom.draganddrop, PID: 1270
                                                                             Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack, iconPack:org.cyanogenmod.hexolibre, fontPkg:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack}
                                                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
                                                                                 at com.example.anandzoom.draganddrop.MainActivity.onDrag(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:19702)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1518)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1518)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1518)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1518)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1518)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1518)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1518)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5290)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.-wrap6(ViewRootImpl.java)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3465)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post the error log

Comment: Do upvote answers that make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the drag listener for Text View and you're trying to cast the Text view to Linear Layout in the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot... it worked... btw can you please explain me what's going on in the ACTION_DROP case... like what does the following 4 lines of code do?

Comment: ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
owner.removeView(view);
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
container.addView(view);

Comment: view.getParent() return  the parent view of the view. owner.removeView(view) removes the view from parent and container.addView(view) adds the view to the container. Doesn't make any sense though.

Answer (score 0):

Your TextView in XML is as below, this is where you are setting the Drag Listener.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_drop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drop here"
        />
```

Now you are typecasting a `TextView` on to a `LinearLayout`, which has nothing to do with your Drag and Drop code hence the exception.

Comment: I'm asking the same question to you. Please explain me these 4 lines of code.                 ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent(); owner.removeView(view); LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview; container.addView(view);